# Is it possible to force login for comments only on custom-post-type or the custom comment template?

Tags: comment-form, comments-template

I use a custom page template `review-template` for my custom post type `reviews`. And on my template, I use a custom comment form `review-comments`.

Now... How do I enable login only for my `review-comments` but not for my posts and other custom post types comments?

Answer (score 0):

First, you will need to go into the comments template file and use [`get_post_type()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_post_type/) to check if the post type is `reviews`.

Then check if the user is logged in using [`is_user_logged_in()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/is_user_logged_in/).

If they are **not** logged in display message: "You must be logged in to post a comment."

If they **are** logged in, display the comment form.